# Extract CDATA from RSS XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, cdata

I have extracted RSS feed content using JS, however the 'Description' node contains CDATA and I want to split this out.

For example, for each Description node under Item I would like to extract only the content that is from `<b>Brief Description:</b>` to the first `</div>` .

Is this possible? Below is an exmaple of what I have thus far and also the xml from the RSS feed below.

Hope someone can help :)

**Script Example**

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","help/Sandbox/XML%20Playground/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B1D503F3E%2D4BFF%2D4248%2D848D%2DE12B5B67DAEC%7D",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;



function media(){

description=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('description');
a=2;
b=1;

for (i=0;i<18;i++)
{



document.write('<p>' + description[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</p>');

b++;
a++;

};

};



</SCRIPT>
```

**RSS XML FEED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--RSS generated by Windows SharePoint Services V3 RSS Generator on 8/03/2011 10:51:51 AM-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/_layouts/RssXslt.aspx?List=1d503f3e-4bff-4248-848d-e12b5b67daec" version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>XML Playground: Media News</title>
    <link>/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/AllItems.aspx</link>
    <description>RSS feed for the Media News list.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 07 Mar 2011 23:51:51 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Windows SharePoint Services V3 RSS Generator</generator>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <image>
      <title>XML Playground: Media News</title>
      <url>/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/_layouts/images/homepage.gif</url>
      <link>help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/AllItems.aspx</link>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>new Item</title>
      <link>/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/DispForm.aspx?ID=2</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Brief Description:</b> <div>bla blah blah ablkahgohoihjsdofsdf dfhfgh</div></div>
<div><b>Thumbnail:</b> <a href="/news/PublishingImages/MySchool_rollup-120-x-120_new-040311.gif">test image</a></div>
]]></description>
      <author>WALKER,Andrew</author>
      <pubDate>Mon, 07 Mar 2011 05:43:19 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http:/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/DispForm.aspx?ID=2</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>My School 2.0 launched</title>
      <link>http://dnet.hosts.network/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/DispForm.aspx?ID=1</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Brief Description:</b> <div>On Friday 4 March 2011 the Minister for School Education, Peter Garrett, launched My School 2.0.</div></div>
<div><b>Thumbnail:</b> <a href="http://dnet.hosts.network/news/PublishingImages/MySchool_rollup-120-x-120_new-040311.gif"></a></div>
<div><b>Release Date:</b> 16/03/2011</div>
]]></description>
                <pubDate>Fri, 04 Mar 2011 04:34:11 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">/help/Sandbox/XML Playground/Lists/Media News/DispForm.aspx?ID=1</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA section content is just text, so you can't parse its contents further using the DOM. You can either use `DOMParser()` to reconstruct the string contents of the CDATA section back into XML and use DOM methods from there, or else use regular expressions.

To use the latter approach, change your `document.write()` line to this:

```
// Slice off 5 characters to get rid of the parent <div> and use [\s\S] to mean
//   any character including newlines up until the first closing div tag
document.write('<p>' + description[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue.slice(5).match(/[\s\S]*?<\/div>/) + '</p>');
```

To use the former approach, which is less than ideal in this case but could be helpful in other situations, you could do this inside the for loop:

```
var cdataContent = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+description[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</div>', 'text/xml').documentElement;
document.body.appendChild(cdataContent.firstChild);
```

...but being sure to only invoke `media()` after the DOM content has loaded.

And maybe you have some good reason for it, but based on the code you supplied, it'd be a lot simpler just to do this:

```
for (i=1; i<description.length; i++) {
```

...and forget about a and b (i.e., change b to i)

And one tip: if you construct the RSS yourself, note that you won't be able to use CDATA sections nested within CDATA sections.