# Using Regular Expression in Javascript to grab text between RSS/XML tag

Tags: xml, regex, json, rss

I'm creating a jQuery Mobile app that parses an RSS feed and dynamically inputs the entries into the DOM.  I'm using the `.contentSnippet` feature to grab the first sentence or two from the `<description>...</description>` and I'd like to just have the content between `<em>...</em>`.  How do I select this content using Javascript and RegEx?  Here is what the RSS looks like that I'm working with.

`<description><![CDATA[<font size="2"><em>American Banker Magazine (03/13) Fest, Glen</em>...</description>`

I'm bringing the feed in as a JSON object.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . Don't use Regular Expressions, instead use an XML Parser,

Comment: similar question : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227592/extract-cdata-from-rss-xml-using-javascript`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want to use a regular expression, you could use

```
var str = '<description><![CDATA[<font size="2"><em>American Banker Magazine (03/13) Fest, Glen</em>...</description>',
    m = str.match( /<em>(.+?)<\/em>/ );

console.log( m && m[1] || 'Nothing doing' );
// American Banker Magazine (03/13) Fest, Glen
```